# JasperSoft JSON data source для fields

Tags: jasperreports, jasperstudio

Неделю пытаюсь заставить Jasper Studio отобразить в отчёте значения из json'a.
Прописал в отчёте (для примера) два филда (fields), например, key и value.
Прописал в области Delail (область на странице отчёта) два text field'а (текстовых поля, динамических).
В первом текстовом поле прописал отображать $F{key}, во втором - $F{value}.
Далее - правой кнопкой на корень иерархии отчёта (от которого все подобъекты идут в древовидной структуре) - Dataset & Query.
Там выбираю вместо SQL - JSON источник данных.
И дальше - пишу что-то вроде:

```
{[{"key":"aaa","value":"bbbb"},{"key":"aaa","value":"bbbb"},{"key":"aaa","value":"bbbb"}]}
```

И дальше попадаю в тупик - на нажатие кнопки Read Fields никакой реакции.
В Data preview - ничего нового не отображается.

С Parameters - всё просто - прописал их в свойствах отчёта, в Preview (нижняя третья вкладка) указал для них значения - и готово, они на форме. А как fields тестировать - всё никак не найду ответа.

Помогите понять, как вывести тестовые значения для fields (двух-трёх однотипных объектов) в отчёте, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге: нужно создать собственный Data Adapter. Прописать в нём то, что это JSON адаптер и указать json файл-источник данных.
После этого - использовать этот адаптер в превью, как источник.